# K8S topologySpreadConstraints does not work as expected

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

EKS v1.24

I defined in a deployment `topologySpreadConstraints` as follows:

```
    spec:
      .
      .
      template:
        .
        .
        spec:
          topologySpreadConstraints:
            - maxSkew: 2
              topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
              whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
            - maxSkew: 1
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
              whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
```

The deployment has 3 replicas.

I expect all 3 pods to come up in different nodes (there are enough nodes that satisfy the pod’s labels / other requirements).

However, K8S put 2 of the pods in the same node.

Why does that happen?